# Parameter reset on dynamic prompt in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have used dynamic parameter in crystal report, in this  when i add "@prmStartDate" and "@prmEndDate" data in first prompt, then second prompt open of dynamic parameter
 but problem is "@prmStartDate" and "@prmEndDate" are reset in second prompt like

I have search for solutions all the place but i can't find answer, please help me.

Comment: didn't got your problem... can you elaborate? `reset` where it is getting resetted? example or a screenshot will be helpful

Comment: I am use grouping in crystal report by dynamic parameter, "@prmEndDate" and "@prmEndDate" are store procedure parameter, so i add this parameter in crystal report(in prompt), then second prompt of grouping parameter open, but in this prompt  "@prmEndDate" and "@prmEndDate" both reset

Comment: to the extent I understand your question.. you have two SP parameters and you use these parameters again in creating dynamic parameters in CR...now what is this `second prompt` of grouping...

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/3pkw4lwxl/ ----see this image for help. problem is is second image

Comment: first thing I see in screenshot... is there are no dynamic parameters... and I suppose you have set some static value while createing parameter.

Comment: dynamic parameter is bellow in second image that you can not see, but problem is not dynamic parameter problem is in "@prmEndDate" and "@prmEndDate", when i click in ok button in first(image) prompt then second prompt(second image) open but parameter value of "@prmEndDate" and "@prmEndDate" change(reset) in second prompt